# Common param Configuration for multiple appender in log4j.xml

Tags: logging, log4j, appender, rollingfileappender

I am trying to create multiple appenders. Every appender will have different log file location.Rest of the param are same.
eg.
I have 2 appender which are just different with only file location param.
I need some way so that i can make a config value and insert in both 
appender for common param.I am using log4j 1.X

eg. i have created someconfiguration element and put similar param to this which 
    i can inject in other appenders so that i do not need to pass same param 
    again and again with every appender.

```
<someconfiguration name ="reuseParam">
 <param name="Append" value="true" />
            <param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true" />

            <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB" />
            <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />

            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n" />
            </layout>
</someconfiguration>


     <appender name="A1" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
            <param name="File" value="D\:\\P1\\applogs\\A1.log" />
            <param name="Append" value="true" />
            <param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true" />

            <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB" />
            <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />

            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n" />
            </layout>
        </appender>

         <appender name="A2" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
            <param name="File" value="D\:\\P2\\applogs\\A2.log" />
            <param name="Append" value="true" />
            <param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true" />
            <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB" />
            <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />

            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
```